# PHP: problems with inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance

I try to do class tree  where each class in tree check own directory for template and use it, but when I call function in inherited class then called parent. How can i do it ?

My code in example below output:

> D
>   C
>   b/1.phtml

but i need to **d/1.phtml**

```
<?php

class A {
    private $templates_dir = 'a';
}

class B extends A {

    private $templates_dir = 'b';

    public function templates_dir()
    {
        return $this->templates_dir;
    }

    public function check_template($tpl)
    {
        $dir = $this->templates_dir();
        $file = $dir. '/'. $tpl;
        echo (get_class($this)). "\r\n";
        echo (get_parent_class($this)). "\r\n";
        echo $file . "\r\n";
// idea  - if (!file_exists($file)) return parent::check_template($file);
// method call each class while template will be found
// how do it?


    }

}

class C extends B {

    private $templates_dir = 'c';

}

class D extends C {

    private $templates_dir = 'd';

}

$obj = new D();
$obj->check_template('1.phtml');
```

Comment: With all those subclasses you're entering in a world of pain.

Answer (score 1):

I would just make `$templates_dir` protected:

```
class A {
   protected $templates_dir = 'a';
}
```

and adjust the extending classes to do the same.

That will then cause `templates_dir()` to return whatever `$templates_dir` is set to.

Comment: Thanks, it's solution for templates_dir, but the main idea is redefine template and without redefine function check_template in each child class calling parent:check_template call first parent class where is defined.

Comment: I want each class in class tree find template in own templates dir and if there is not template call immediate parent class for check this template in own templates_dir and further until the template is found

Answer (score 1):

Another approach will be placing the functions in a abstract class, and each of class A,B,C,D extends this, This is a neater way of doing things.

Below is the code --

```
    abstract class WW {

    protected function templates_dir()
    {
        return $this->templates_dir;
    }

    public function check_template($tpl)
    {
        $dir = $this->templates_dir();
        $file = $dir. '/'. $tpl;
        echo (get_class($this)). "\r\n";
        echo (get_parent_class($this)). "\r\n";
        echo $file . "\r\n";
    // idea  - if (!file_exists($file)) return parent::check_template($file);
    // method call each class while template will be found
    // how do it?


    }
}

class A extends WW {
    protected $templates_dir = 'a';
}

class B extends WW {

    protected $templates_dir = 'b';



}

class C extends WW {

    protected $templates_dir = 'c';

}

class D extends WW {

    protected $templates_dir = 'd';



}

$obj = new D();
$obj->check_template('1.phtml');
```